# How do you open .mat files in Octave?

Tags: matlab, terminal, octave, mat-file

I have a `.mat` file that I want to open and see its contents. Since I don't have MATLAB, I downloaded GNU's Octave. I'm working on Mac's terminal so I'm not exactly sure how to open the `.mat` file to see its contents.

How to do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Not sure which version of `.mat` file you might have, or whether Octave keeps up with the latest Matlab formats.

[Here's a link that might be a good start](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Octave_Programming_Tutorial/Saving_and_loading_a_MAT-file).

Bottom line is that you can say:  `load MyMatFile.mat` right at the Octave prompt.

In case you wind up having to write code to read the `.mat` file ever: I've done this before and it was not difficult, but was time-consuming.  [Mat file format for 2012a](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf)

Comment: To be clear, using File > Open > abc.mat did not work for me, but using the load command did.

Answer (score 8):

If your file contains only numbers, no `.mat` header, then this should work:

```
variable = load("filename")
```