# input/output file access with Octave GNU

Tags: c++, matlab, octave

I want to save `mxArray` to an **Octave** `.mat` file.

I created a mex function with c++ in **Octave** that reads binary files and populate the data to an `mxArray`. I would like to visualize these data with Octave. I would like to save the data in an Octave format or `.mat` format. 
with **Matlab**, there are `matOpen()` to open a file, `matClose()` to close the file, and `matPutVariable()` to write the data to the file. what are the equivalent functions in **Octave** the these **Matlab** functions?

Comment: This one might still be relevant even though it's old: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915658/how-do-you-open-mat-files-in-octave

Comment: Try calling Octave to have it execute the `save` function. In MATLAB you’d use `mxCallMatlab`, not sure what the Octave equivalent is.

Comment: Just found `mexCallMatlab` https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Calling-Other-Functions-in-Mex_002dFiles.html#Calling-Other-Functions-in-Mex_002dFiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit :

As proposed in the comments of this (edited) answer : https://github.com/tbeu/matio is designed for that purpose. 
In an edit proposition the OP said :

> this solved the issue. matio seems not optimized as Matlab library though.

Comment: Missed the mex file part.. https://github.com/tbeu/matio
seems to be designed for that purpose.

Comment: I used matio and compared it to Matlab library. Using the same input file. Matlab mex library produced 406kb output file. Matio produced 2Mb. I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: Have you figured out a way to answer the question in this post ? If yes you should post or accept an answer in order to help the next persons that will encounter the same problem as you. For your new question it is better to ask a new question as an independent post.